# Check items from a List of ValueTuple and return results in another List of ValueTuple C#7

Tags: list, multiple-conditions, valuetuple, c#-7.3

Please consider the following list of ValueTuple C#7

```
static void Main(string[] args)

{

 List<(double prices, int matches)> myList = new List<(double, int)>();

                myList.Add((100, 10));  

                myList.Add((100.50 , 12)); 

                myList.Add((101 , 14));

                myList.Add((101.50 , 16));

}
```

What would be a simple way to search for items meeting conditions for "prices" AND "matches" within the List and return the results in another List of ValueTuple.

For instance if I want to return another List of ValueTuples meeting "prices > 101 and matches > 6"

Can you post an example please?

Answer (score 1):

It's easier if you give names to the items :

```
var myList = new List<(double d,int i)>
             {
                 (100, 10),
                 (100.50 , 12),
                 (101 , 14),
                 (101.50 , 16)
             };

var results = myList.Where(x => x.d>101 && x.i>6);
```

Without the names you'd have to write

```
var results = myList.Where(x => x.Item1>101 && x.Item2>6);
```

C# 7.3 added tuple equality but not comparison. You can now write :

```
var result = myList.Where(d=>d == (101,14));
```

and

```
var result = myList.Where(d=>d != (101,14));
```

But not

```
var result = myList.Where(d=>d > (101,14));
```